# Cannot get Double-Shift working on Visual Studio + ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

To clarify that it is not an duplicate - I have my ReSharper shortcuts working in general, this is not the issue!

The issue is that I got used to using Double-Shift to trigger 'Search Everywhere' and it does not work in VS which is really annoying.

Sticky keys are not enabled for sure - all options on 'Set up Sticky keys' page of Control Panel are unchecked.

Any ideas?